# Update Parent table from Child Table using SqlCommand

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlcommand

I have 2 tables:

- `WorkSchedule` which has 2 columns `WorkScheduleID` and `WorkScheduleStatus`
- `WorkShiftBid` which has 3 columns: `WorkShiftBidID`, `WSBidStatus`, `WorkScheduleID` (foreign key to `WorkSchedule` table)

I want to update the `WorkSchedule` table from the `WorkShiftBid` table. So this is roughly how it goes:

I press a button in my website, it reads the current `WorkShiftBidID` and updates the `WSBidStatus` to 'Approved'.

However, I want to update `WorkScheduleStatus` and `WSBidStatus` in both tables to 'Approved' where `WorkScheduleID` in both tables is the same.

I came up with this query but it is not working:

```
com.CommandText = "update WorkShiftBid b, WorkSchedule w" +
                  "set b.WSBidStatus ='Approved' and w.WorkScheduleStatus = 'Approved'" +
                  "where WorkShiftBidID = @id and w.WorkScheduleID = b.WorkScheduleID";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

How should I change it to work?

Comment: Write a stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot update 2 tables with a single update command. However you can execute 2 updates in a single batch or send them as 2 batches if you like:

```
com.CommandText = @"update WorkShiftBid
  set WSBidStatus ='Approved'
  where WorkShiftBidID = @id;

update w
  set WorkScheduleStatus = 'Approved'
from WorkSchedule w
  inner join WorkShiftBid b
     on w.WorkScheduleID = b.WorkScheduleID
  where WorkShiftBidID = @id";

com.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
```

Comment: If you're using a `from WorkSchedule w` in your second `UPDATE` statement, then you **must use** `UPDATE w` (using the **alias**) in T-SQL

Comment: I got this problem: "SqlException: Invalid object name 'WorkShiftBidID'." When I ran, it only updated the `WSBidStatus` in the `WorkShiftBid` Table. However, it was unable to update the `WorkSchedule` Table. I think something went wrong in the second part of the query.

Comment: @addsw,probably I wrote your table name wrong. Editing.